# Нужно ли двоеточие? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, двоеточие

> Откуда пошла полюбившаяся многим фраза(:) «Никто никому ничего не должен»?

Должно ли на месте скобок стоять двоеточие? Постоянно путаюсь в подобных конструкциях, хотелось бы ссылку на правило. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Игорь, мне кажется не очень корректно принимать ответ, а потом отменять его. В этом случае участник получает минус 15 баллов, и это выглядит как "наказание", но вы же не хотите его "наказывать"? Лучше не принимать ответ сразу, подождать другие.  Впрочем, это мое личное мнение, это просто совет.

Comment: @Sharon  Спасибо за поддержку! Я ваш ответ отметил стрелочкой. Но всё же остаюсь при своём мнении. Возможны оба варианта – выбор за автором текста. Для меня при двоеточии нужно явно понижать голос на слове "фраза". Я же читаю это предложение с ударением на первых словах и выделением этого слова с повышением тона голоса.

Comment: @ Александр Стрелец Если фраза короткая, то я тоже могу прочитать. с ударением на первых словах, но потом его не буду понижать. А вы, вероятно, собираетесь это сделать, так как повышенный тон не выдержать до конца. Получится, что вопросительная интонация не обозначена, работает только вопросительное слово. А вот при постановке двоеточия мы совершенно свободны в своем выборе: ударение можно ставить в любом месте, так как у каждой части своя интонационная схема. Но хотя у нас разные мнения, вы мне очень помогли определиться в этой теме, спасибо вам. Вот только опять куда-то пропали.

Comment: То есть мне снять галочку с вашего и поставить ее на ответ Александра?

Comment: Всё. Я вам еще сообщение на почту написал, может, в спам попало.

Comment: Хорошо! Можно удалить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Откуда пошла полюбившаяся многим фраза **«Никто никому ничего не должен»**?*

[Из справочника Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154):

> **Примечание**. Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится:
> *Он вспомнил пословицу **«За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймаешь»** и отказался от первоначального плана*.
>
> Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова ***предложение, выражение, надпись*** и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие:
> *Мимо станции проносились скорые поезда с табличками на вагонах: **«Москва — Владивосток»***; *Разберите предложение: **«Сверкнула молния, и грянул гром»***.

В справочнике Лопатина такого дополнения (о словах *предложение* и т. п.)  нет.

[Из ответа справочной службы русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20) на вопрос № 304997:

> *Однажды я застал забавный диалог, один из участников которого задавался вопросом «Почему в нашем мире нет магии?»*.
>
> Возможен и другой вариант.
>
> *Однажды я застал забавный диалог, один из участников которого задавался вопросом: «Почему в нашем мире нет магии?»*

В предложении из вопроса я бы не стал ставить двоеточие в силу интонационного момента. Перед двоеточием обычно делается значительная пауза, а голос понижается (почти как в конце предложения). Здесь же, напротив, голос чуть повышается на слове "*фраза*" и делается короткая (произносительная) пауза.

Comment: Александр,  у меня к вам такой вопрос. Вы в своем варианте без двоеточия обозначаете вопросительную интонацию (повышение голоса в конце предложения)? Мне кажется. что как-то сложно ее обозначить.

Comment: Нет, в конце не делаю повышение. Это же не обязательно для постановки "?". Голосовые сообщения бы здесь не помешали.

Comment: А почему не обязательно?

Comment: _Она пошла в магаз**И**н?_ – повышение в конце. _Он**А** пошла в магазин?_ – снижение в конце.

Comment: "ОнА пошла в магазин".Я полагаю, что снижения в конце не должно быть вообще. Ровная интонация сохраняется после повышения, но больше не понижается.  Иначе вопрос "потеряется".

Comment: _Она пошл**А** в магазин?_ – и здесь делается снижение в конце. Я согласен с тем, что снижение не такое, как в утвердительных предложениях (хотя даже в них можно сделать акцент на конце и повысить тон: _Она пошла в магаз**И**н_. А не куда-то еще). "Кульминация" высоты голоса идет на тех словах, которые имеют значение для вопрошающего. В предложении из вопроса тоже сохраняется не то чтобы вопросительная интонация в конце, а... как бы это сказать... посыл, исходящий от слова "откуда".

Comment: Интонация, конечно, дело смутное, спорить сложно.  Я полагаю, что тон понижать нельзя. В коротких предложения его держать довольно просто, но наше предложение длинное, от вопроса там ничего не останется.  К тому же вы, кажется,  повышаете тон на слове «фраза», это ударная позиция для вопроса? Откуда пошла полюбившаяся многим фрАза  /«Никто никому ничего не должен». Я не чувствую там основного вопросительного ударения.

Comment: Сравним: ОткУда пошлА / эта полюбившаяся многим фраза?  Здесь ударение я делаю на одном из слов в первой части, а потом держу его ровно. Вопросительное слово  необязательно ударное, поэтому даже при его наличии не стоит отказываться от интонации вопроса.  Извините за расспросы,  просто действительно  интересно. Спасибо вам за ваше мнение.

Comment: И вам спасибо! Действительно, в длинных предложениях масса вариантов. Я почти не повышаю голос на "фраза", но выделяю ее, т. к. полное снижение будет неуместно. А основное ударение тоже делаю на первых словах.

Answer (score 2):

**А. Ответ на вопрос**

1. Подобные  предложения имеют **два варианта оформления**:  (1) по классическому образцу для  прямой речи (две **самостоятельные** части, разделенные двоеточием);  (2) текст **встраивается** в предложение и теряет самостоятельность.

Грамматика во втором случае такова. Слова  «фраза, выражение, вопрос, надпись»  являются **приложениями** к  тому содержанию, которое заключено в кавычках.  Вряд ли можно согласиться с тем, что оформление зависит **от семантики** этих слов – здесь всем правит  структура и интонация предложения.

Иногда возможны **оба варианта**,  и мы выбираем подходящий. Но иногда по каким-либо причинам подходит **только один вариант**. Таким образом, задача получается творческая, интересная, не формальная по решению.

2. И вот в заданном предложении я бы однозначно использовала **только один вариант** – с двоеточием, причем это связано  **с вопросом, отнесенным к его первой части:**

*Откуда пошла полюбившаяся многим фраза: **«Никто никому ничего не должен»?***

**Пояснение**

1. Как **вообще** выглядит  **интонация** предложения с прямой речью и словами автора?

Предложение делится **на две части**, причем каждая часть имеет свою **собственную** интонацию. На письме они разделены двоеточием, а в устной речи голос **в конце первой части понижается** (неполное понижение), делается четко обозначенная предупредительная **пауза**, а далее следует вторая часть.

2. Но так оформляется **повествовательное предложение**, а у нас первая часть вопросительная. Здесь интонация **особая.**

**Повышение тона** (обозначение вопроса) делается  на одном из слов в первой части, далее предупредительная пауза, а вторая часть произносится с **понижением** голоса. И вот что мы получаем:

**Откуда пошла  / полюбившаяся многим **фрАза**: «Никто никому / ничего **не дОлжен**»?**

3. Оформить такое вопросительное предложение как простое можно, если оно короткое, например:   *Откуда же **взялАсь** фраза / «Никто никому не должен»?*

В простом предложении мы повышаем голос на одном из слов в первой части и больше его не понижаем, **чтобы обозначить вопрос**.  Но такая интонация возможна в нераспространенном предложении.

Таким образом, деление предложение **двоеточием**  на две части позволяет нам обозначить вопрос **только в первой части**,  а далее **понизить тон**. Если же двоеточия нет (простое предложение), то вопросительную интонацию приходится **сохранять до конца предложения**, а это не очень удобно.

**Б. Коротко рассмотрим  примеры**

**1. Розенталь**

*Он вспомнил пословицу **«За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймАешь»**  / и отказался от первоначального плАна.*

Здесь  интонация простого предложения, но она построена  на обозначении **однородных сказуемых** (там всего две фразы). Текст же пословицы не имеет собственной интонации, он **вписан в общую схему** как ее элемент.

Сравним:  *Тут он вспомнил/ известную послОвицу: // **«За двумя зайцами погОнишься — ни одного не поймАешь»**.*

Это уже оформление по образцу прямой речи,  интонация  пословицы (в том числе деление паузой/тире  на две части)  обозначается отдельно.

**2. Грамота.ру**

Приведены **два варианта** оформления одного и того же предложения. Первый вариант мне кажется более **предпочтительным**, так как в этом случае нет особой необходимости  для интонационного выделения прямой речи.

(1)  *Однажды я застал забавный диалОг, один из участников которого задавался вопросом /  **«Почему в нашем мире нет мАгии?»**.*

Примечание. **Отличие** от нашего варианта заключается  в том, что вопрос относится ко второй части, а не к первой.

Это **сложноподчиненное** предложение (не простое). Оно делится на две части запятой. Вторая часть распространенная, поэтому она также делится произносительной паузой на две части. Текстовая часть вопросительная, но это никак не обозначается интонацией (**встроенный текст**), в конце предложения стоит точка, делается  понижение тона.

(2) *Однажды я застал забавный диалОг, один из участников которого задавался вопрОсом: **«ПочемУ в нашем мире  / нет магии?»***

Здесь оформление по образцу прямой речи,   **вторая часть имеет самостоятельную интонацию:** повышение тона на вопросительном слове и  сохранение ровного тона до конца предложения (без его понижения).

Так мы  выделяем текст вопроса **в самостоятельную структуру**, как бы сами задаем его.