# Период и сложноподчинённое предложение

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, спп, сложное-предложение

В справочнике Розенталя, в правиле, посвящённом запятой и тире, написано следующее:

> Действующими правилами предусмотрено употребление запятой и тире в качестве единого знака препинания в трех случаях:
>
> 1. перед главной частью сложноподчиненного предложения, которому предшествует ряд однородных придаточных, для подчеркивания распадения единого целого на две части;
> 2. перед словом, которое повторяется для того, чтобы связать с ним дальнейшую часть того же предложения;
> 3. в периоде для указания перехода от повышения к понижению[21].

Определение периода у Розенталя вот такое:

> В периоде (**как правило, многочленном сложном предложении, в интонационном отношении распадающемся на две части — повышение и понижение**) ...

Возникает вопрос: разве В 1-м пункте в 1-го правила не описывается один из примеров периода? По-моему, сложноподчинённое предложение, в котором главной части предшествует ряд однородных придаточных и которое распадается на 2 части (1-й пункт) подпадает под определение периода, данное Розенталем. Следовательно, если это так, зачем нужен 1-й пункт 1-го правила? Может, для удобства и систематизации справочника Розенталь вынес частный случай одного из пунктов в отдельный?

Comment: Игорь, пожалуйста, давайте ссылки на источники, которые вы цитируете, так будет намного легче отвечать на ваши вопросы

Comment: Буду иметь в виду, благодарствую)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Это «период»:

***Как ни старались люди**, собравшись в одно небольшое место несколько сот тысяч, изуродовать ту землю, на которой они жались, **как ни забивали камнями землю**, чтобы ничего не росло на ней, *как ни счищали всякую пробивающуюся травку, как ни дымили каменным углем и нефтью, как ни обрезывали деревья и ни выгоняли всех животных и птиц,* — весна была весною даже и в городе* (Л. Т.);

Это СПП:

***Кто виноват из них, кто прав**, — судить не нам* (Кр.); ***Делал ли что-нибудь для этого Штольц, что делал и как делал**,* — мы этого не знаем (Добр.);

2. Часто они **взаимозаменяемы.** Например, "период" можно превратить в СПП, если убрать распространители и оставить основную структуру. СПП можно превратить в период, если распространить придаточные предложения.
3. **Но зачем это делать?**  Здесь у нас два вида синтаксических конструкций, и  неудивительно, что каждая рассматривается отдельно, в своей теме.

Под понятие «период» могут подходить конструкции **другого типа**, где распространители передают основное содержание, а главная структура  объединяет их только формально. У Толстого, к примеру,  есть «периоды» объемом на полстраницы.

Главное для периода – это **повтор** однотипных (распространенных) конструкций в первой части предложения. Вторая часть тоже может быть распространенной (но без повтора).

**Интонационно** при постановке запятой и тире  СПП и "период" похожи: восходяще-нисходящая интонация, подчеркнутая пауза. Но в СПП единый знак не является обязательным, там и **запятая** возможна, если нет увеличенной паузы.

4. Конструкции с названием «период» рассматривались еще  **в Правилах 1956 года**.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (ответ на  комментарий автора)

1. **Многие «периоды» построены на основе СПП с особой структурой:** период образуют однородные придаточные, а главное предложение относится ко второй части.

Но вот  «распространители» у придаточных  тоже особые – это предложения, связанные с однородным придаточным **подчинительной связью**.

Поэтому  «период» можно считать **распространенным вариантом СПП особой структуры,** где сочетается параллельная и последовательная подчинительная связь. И тогда  такой «период» – это очень **частный случай СПП.**

2. Но периоды могут иметь **и другую повторяющуюся структуру.** Так, у  Розенталя есть пример, где повторяется конструкция на основе существительного ***степи*** с разными определителями (придаточные определительные, причастный оборот). http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=153#pp153

В принципе никаких особых ограничений здесь нет, а требование одно –  несколько **одинаково построенных  (повторяющихся) структур**, отнесенных ко второй части «периода».

Поэтому СПП и «периоды» изучаются отдельно, у каждой конструкции есть свои грамматические особенности и правила постановки знаков препинания

Comment: Как всегда, вам огромное спасибо! Но вы говорите, что  «"период" можно превратить в СПП, если убрать распространители и оставить основную структуру». Но разве наличие распространителей в предложении сразу говорит о том, что это период? Почему первое предложение не считать просто СПП: ряд однородных придаточных имеется, а распространены они или нет — разве имеет значение? Извиняюсь, если не прав.

Comment: Игорь, ответ на ваш комментарий я поместила в дополнении к своему ответу, а к вам у меня такой вопрос: почему вы не пользуетесь Справочником Розенталя, который используют все и на который  очень удобно давать ссылки.  Содержание у двух изданий примерно одинаковое. И еще такая просьба: прочитайте, пожалуйста,  мой комментарий к вопросу https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461427/Нужно-ли-двоеточие-2/461431#461431 , мне кажется, вы его просто не видели.

Comment: Спасибо! Конечно, я пользуюсь справочником Розенталя, но забываю цитировать. Исправлюсь)